# Java - How to open the windows console from a java program

Tags: java

I want to open the "program" `start.bat` but I have an error:

> java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)

This is my code:

```
File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop");

try {
    Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process p = r.exec("start.bat /c start command", null, file);
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `cmd /c` to the command. Example

```
Process p = r.exec("cmd /c start start.bat", null, file);
```

Comment: @Arthur yeah. You can replace it with any command you want. In your case `start.bat`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `cmd /c` to your command.

Here is a little tip,

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/42644